# Is "the RDA method" redundant?

Tags: phrase-choice

RDA is the abbreviation of Redundancy analysis.

Can we say "the RDA method"?

Is that redundant? What should I say then?

Comment: You should explain why you think it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Using

> RDA method

is not redundant, it would expand to

> Redundancy Analysis method

the **method** used is Redundancy Analysis